# How to remove "trace" of a mark in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm working on a tracker app and I managed to pull some data from the server and update other user's so called track. But I have this mark .person, which appears on every step. How Should I remove it?

Polyline is drawn like this:

```
private func updateOnlineTrackOnMap() {

    let locations = self.track?.points?.map { $0.location } ?? []
    guard locations.count >= 2 else { return }

    mapView.drawPolyline(withLocations: locations)

    mapView.setMark(.person, to: locations.last!.coordinate)

}
```

But mapView.removeMark(.person) doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: What is `mapView.setMark(.person, to: locations.last!.coordinate)` As far as I know it is not a method of MKMapView. You can add an annotation and remove them. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452409-removeannotation

So please give more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there were some custom methods. I've managed to do the trick like so:

```
if let oldAnnotation = self.drawer.oldAnnotation {

    mapView.removeAnnotation(oldAnnotation)

}

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = locations.last!.coordinate

annotation.title = "Speed"
let speed = locations.last!.speed * 3.6
annotation.subtitle = String(format: "%.2f km/h", speed)

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)

oldAnnotation = annotation
mapView.drawPolyline(withLocations: locations)
```

There's just a global variable to store current annotation coordinate. And then in mapView :viewFor: I wrote something like this:

```
if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Online")
    annotationView.image = rotatedArrow
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true

    return annotationView

}
```